# Type.forName(..) returns null for Unlocked Package with Spring 20' release

Tags: salesforcedx, namespace, second-generation-packaging

It seems that Salesforce Spring 20' release made public classes part of Unlocked 2GP not accessible when @namespaceaccessible is not mentionned. That has a huge impact.

I thought this annotation was only for managed packages ? Is it a bug ?

Comment: Chris Peterson has acknowledged they are looking into the issue. https://twitter.com/ca_peterson/status/1214239843124797440?s=19

Answer (score 5):

This is part of the critical update documented here https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_apex_publicConstructorsInMgdPackages.htm?edition=&impact=

Specifically "Apex classes contained in second-generation packages can instantiate public classes from other packages in the same namespace only if they are annotated @NamespaceAccessible."

However if you are saying this is happening when the critical update is disabled in the org then it is possibly a bug. I would raise a case with salesforce support.

Comment: Case raised thank you !